# Elasticsearch count of searches against an index resets to zero after cluster restart

Tags: elasticsearch

We use Elasticsearch - one cluster is 7.16 and another is 8.4.  Behavior is the same in both.

We need to be able to get a count of search queries run against an index since the index's creation.

We retrieve the amount of searches that have been run against a given index by using the `_stats` endpoint as such:

`GET /_stats?filter_path=indices.my_index.primaries.search.query_total`

The problem is that this stat resets to zero after a cluster reboot.  Does this data persist anywhere for a given index such that I can get the total since inception of the index?  If not, is there an action I can take to somehow record that stat before a reboot so I can always access the full total number?

EDIT - this is the only item I was able to find on this subject, and the answer in this discussion does not look promising: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-close-reopen-index-will-reset-index-stats-to-zero/170830

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no Out of the box solution to achieve your use-case, but its not that hard to build it yourself either, You can simply call the same _stats API periodically and store it in some other index of Elasticsearch or DB so that its not reset. IMHO Its not that big work.